# MVC renew ` __RequestVerificationToken` token when logging in via angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC website with some AngularJS components.

When I make a post request using angularjs, I always include the `__RequestVerificationToken` token from a hidden input on the page.

My problem is this:

User starts an anonymous session i.e not logged in.

The user logs in using angularjs component, which sends a post request.
My MVC controller validates the credentials and the '__RequestVerificationToken'. Once the user is logged in, it returns a the new token.

The angularjs controller then takes the new token and updates the hidden input to be used for any future requests.

However the next request I make using angularjs fails the validation because the 
`var tokenCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName);` (see below code sample) is still the old token from the anonymous session.

Although the "X-XSRF-Token" (see below code sample) is coming through as the new one.

How do I also update/renew the http cookie (tokenCookie) containing the token to the new one?

I have posted copy of my code below.

My action filter:

```
public sealed class WebApiValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
            var headers = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers;

            var tokenCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName);

            var tokenHeader = string.Empty;
            if (headers.AllKeys.Contains("X-XSRF-Token"))
            {
                tokenHeader = headers.GetValues("X-XSRF-Token").FirstOrDefault();
            }

           AntiForgery.Validate(tokenCookie != null ? tokenCookie.Value : null, tokenHeader);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

My login controller:

```
[WebApiValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult login(string email, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

    var rq = HttpContext.Request;
    var r = validateLogin(email, password, true); // my login handling
    if (r.Success)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

        // within an action construct AJAX response and pass updated token to client
        return Json(new
        {
            __RequestVerificationToken = UpdateRequestVerificationToken(Request)
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// resets AntiForgery validation token and update a cookie
/// The new antiforgery cookie is set as the results and sent
/// back to client with Ajax
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Request">request from current context</param>
/// <returns>string - a form token to pass to AJAX response</returns>
private string UpdateRequestVerificationToken(HttpRequestBase Request)
{
    string formToken;
    string cookieToken;
    const string __RequestVerificationToken = "__RequestVerificationToken";
    AntiForgery.GetTokens(Request.Form[__RequestVerificationToken], out cookieToken, out formToken);
    if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(__RequestVerificationToken))
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[__RequestVerificationToken];
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Name = __RequestVerificationToken;
        cookie.Value = cookieToken;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    return formToken;
}
```

My angularjs Login handling:

```
login(email, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return this.AccountRequest.login(email, password)
            .then(response => {
                const newToken = response.data['__RequestVerificationToken'];
                const oldTokenElement = angular.element('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]');
                oldTokenElement.val(newToken); // confirmed the new token has been updated in the hidden element

                resolve(this.refresh.bind(this));
            });
    })
}
```

Every time I make a post request using angularjs:

```
post(uri, queryParams = {}, data = null) {

    this.$http.defaults.headers.common['X-XSRF-Token'] = angular.element('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').attr('value');
    this.$http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest'; // Needed to ensure we get back http error instead of a webpage
    const config = this.makeConfig('POST', uri, queryParams, data);

    return this.$http(config);
}

makeConfig(method, uri, params = {}, data = null) {
    return {
        method,
        data,
        params,
        url: uri.toString(),
    };
}
```

Comment: Is your AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName = "__RequestVerificationToken"? This is because the cookie that you get and set is different, hence why OnActionExecuting is still reading the old value .

Comment: The cookie and cookie name is set by MVC and yes it is `__RequestVerificationToken`. Could you clarify the reason for me? or point me to some documentation I could read up? any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks a bit off with how you are assigning the value to the existing cookie.

> Your method has a mismatch of the token that the method returns (`formToken`) and what is being set in your cookie (`cookieToken`). Pay attention to the last line of the method...

```
const string __RequestVerificationToken = "__RequestVerificationToken";
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[__RequestVerificationToken];

// check for null
if (cookie == null)
{
    // no cookie found, create it... or respond with an error
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

// grab the cookie
AntiForgery.GetTokens(
    Request.Form[__RequestVerificationToken],
    out string cookieToken, 
    out string formToken);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieToken)
{
    // update the cookie value(s)
    cookie.Values[__RequestVerificationToken] = cookieToken;
    //...
}

// update the expiration timestamp
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30);

// overwrite the cookie
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

// return the NEW token!
return cookieToken;
```

---

**Side note..**

You probably shouldn't be using `const` here...

```
const newToken = response.data['__RequestVerificationToken']; // <-- doesn't look right...
const oldTokenElement = angular.element('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]');
```

A `const` will not allow you to reassign the value. Therefore, the `newToken` will never get reassigned the new token value at the client side. You might want to consider using a `let` or a `var` here instead.